# Не вводится пароль при пуше проекта с Idea на GiThub

Tags: java, intellij-idea, github

Не вводится пароль к терминале в IDEA при пуше проекта на ГитХаб: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Есть сообщение в консоли, что не так.

> remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13,
> 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.

Вместо пароля используй сгенерированный токен. Как его создать и использовать можно посмотреть в [документации](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

Также для аутентификации можно использовать SSH ключи вместо пары логин-токен.
[Connecting to GitHub with SSH](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)

Answer (score 0):

иногда github глючит при работе со средами программирования и таким способом не всегда удаётся запушить код. Рекомендую в таких ситуациях использовать git hub desktop

Answer (score 0):

Коллеги, решала проблему. Вставила токен и нажала enter. Просто токен или пароль не отображается в Idea/

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).